# Google app Style help View

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch

So I want to recreate the translucent help overlay found in the google serach application on ios.

The circles glow and when touched bring up text and images describing the functionality of the object underneath.

I've found that I am able to recreate this by simply adding all of the shapes and text with imageViews and Labels, set them to hidden, and when the user presses help unhide them. But this adds a lot of extra objects to each view controller and I would like to make this overlay into its own view or view controller for reusability.

How do you think I should go about this, or How do you think Google did it?

Thanks

Comment: Did you ever get this working?  Any code you can publish?  I am getting the overlay per http://cocoawithlove.com/2009/04/showing-message-over-iphone-keyboard.html But I am not able to register for touches?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think Google also did it with UIImageViews for the circles and UILabels for the texts. You could put all the circles and texts into one UIView, so you only have to hide and show this view when the user taps on help.

So I think you are on the right track.